# How to connect queues to a ZeroMQ PUB/SUB

Tags: zeromq, jeromq

Consider the following:

- a set of 3 logical services: `S1`, `S2` and `S3`
- two instances of each service are running, so we have the following processes: `S1P1`, `S1P2`, `S2P1`, `S2P2`, `S3P1`, `S3P2`
- a `ZeroMQ` broker running in a single process and reachable by all service processes

A logical service, let's say `S1`, publishes a message `M1` that is of interest to logical services `S2` and `S3`. Only one process of each logical service must receive `M1`, so let's say `S2P1` and `S3P2`.

I have tried the following, but without success:

- broker thread 1 is running a **`XSUB/XPUB`** proxy
- broker thread 2 is running a **`ROUTER/DEALER`** proxy with the `ROUTER` connected to the `XPUB` socket and subscribed to everything (for logical `S1`)
- broker thread 3 is running a `ROUTER/DEALER` proxy with the `ROUTER` connected to the `XPUB` socket and subscribed to everything (for logical `S2`)
- broker thread 4 is running a `ROUTER/DEALER` proxy with the `ROUTER` connected to the XPUB socket and subscribed to everything (for logical `S3`)
- each logical service process is running a `REP` socket thread connected to the broker `DEALER` socket

I figured that the `XSUB/XPUB` proxy would give me publish/subscribe semantics and that the `ROUTER/DEALER` proxies would introduce a competition between the `REP` sockets for the messages sent by the `XSUB/XPUB` proxy.

**How can I combine `ZeroMQ` sockets to accomplish this?**

**Update1**

I know "without success" isn't helpful, I've tried different configurations and got different errors.  The latest configuration I tried is the following:

`(XSUB proxy=> XPUB) => (SUB copyLoop=> REQ) => (ROUTER proxy=> DEALER) => REP`

The copyLoop goes like this:

```
public void start() {
    context = ZMQ.context(1);

    subSocket = context.socket(ZMQ.SUB);
    subSocket.connect(subSocketUrl);
    subSocket.subscribe("".getBytes());

    reqSocket = context.socket(ZMQ.REQ);
    reqSocket.connect(reqSocketUrl);

    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        final Message msg = receiveNextMessage();
        resendMessage(msg);
    }
}

private Message receiveNextMessage() {
    final String header = subSocket.recvStr();
    final String entity = subSocket.recvStr();

    return new Message(header, entity);
}

private void resendMessage(Message msg) {
    reqSocket.sendMore(msg.getKey());
    reqSocket.send(msg.getData(), 0);
}
```

The exception I get is the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot send another request
    at zmq.Req.xsend(Req.java:51) ~[jeromq-0.3.4.jar:na]
    at zmq.SocketBase.send(SocketBase.java:613) ~[jeromq-0.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.send(ZMQ.java:1206) ~[jeromq-0.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.sendMore(ZMQ.java:1189) ~[jeromq-0.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.xyz.messaging.zeromq.SubReqProxyConnector.resendMessage(SubReqProxyConnector.java:47) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.xyz.messaging.zeromq.SubReqProxyConnector.start(SubReqProxyConnector.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
```

I'm running JeroMQ 0.3.4, Oracle Java 8 JVM and Windows 7.

Comment: You might want to know that **`ZeroMQ` is broker-less by-design**

Comment: When you say "without success" - what issues are you running into?  I'll suggest an alternate (but similar) architecture in an answer, but it may not be helpful depending on where you're running into issues.

Comment: @Jason You're absolutely right that it wasn't clear - it's because I tried different combinations and got different exceptions.  I've updated the question to reflect the latest configuration.

Comment: @user3666197 Yes I'm aware of that, I'm trying to determine whether I can build a bare-bones broker with ZeroMQ in order to avoid installing a new component like RabbitMQ in a customer's environment.

Comment: @user3666197 I also find it odd that ZeroMQ is marketed as broker-less by design, yet one of the first patterns that are presented in the guide is a pub/sub broker.

Comment: I wouldn't call ZMQ broker-less, I'd say ZMQ is a messaging library at a lower level than the broker.  You design your topology based on your messaging requirements, and if it requires a broker, you build one, if it doesn't you don't.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for the clarification on what's going wrong, that helps me immensely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be adding in some complexity with your `ROUTER` connection - you should be able to do everything connected directly to your publisher.

The error you're currently running into is that `REQ` sockets have a strict message ordering pattern - you are not allowed to `send()` twice in a row, you must send/receive/send/receive/etc (likewise, `REP` sockets must receive/send/receive/send/etc).  From what it looks like, you're just doing send/send/send/etc on your `REQ` socket without ever receiving a response.  If you don't care about a response from your peer, then you must receive and discard it or use `DEALER` (or `ROUTER`, but `DEALER` makes more sense in your current diagram).

I've created a diagram of how I would accomplish this architecture below - using your basic process structure.

```
Broker T1         Broker T2                Broker T3                Broker T4
(PUB*)------>(*SUB)[--](DEALER*)   -->(*SUB)[--](DEALER*)   -->(*SUB)[--](DEALER*)
       |_____________________||____|                  ||    |                  ||
       |_____________________||_______________________||____|                  ||
                             ||                       ||                       ||
     ========================||     ==================||            ===========||=
   ||             ||              ||              ||              ||              ||
   ||             ||              ||              ||              ||              ||
   ||             ||              ||              ||              ||              ||
(REP*)         (REP*)          (REP*)          (REP*)          (REP*)          (REP*)
 S1P1           S1P2            S2P1            S2P2            S3P1            S3P2
```

So, the main difference is that I've ditched your `(SUB copyLoop=> REQ)` step.  Whether you choose `XPUB/XSUB` vs `PUB/SUB` is up to you, but I would tend to start simpler unless you currently want to make use of the extra features of `XPUB/XSUB`.

Obviously this diagram doesn't deal with how information enters your broker, where you currently show an `XSUB` socket - that's out of scope for the information you've provided thus far, presumably you're able to receive information into your broker successfully already so I won't deal with that.

I assume your broker threads that are dedicated to each service are making intelligent choices on whether to send the message to their service or not?  If so, then your choice of having them subscribed to everything should work fine, otherwise more intelligent subscription setups might be necessary.

If you're using a `REP` socket on your service processes, then the service process must take that message and deal with it asynchronously, *never* communicating back any details about that message to the broker.  It must then respond to each message with an acknowledgement (like "RECEIVED") so that it follows the strict receive/send/receive/send pattern for `REP` sockets.

If you want any other type of communication about how the service handles that message sent back to the broker, `REP` is no longer the appropriate socket type for your service processes, and `DEALER` may no longer be the correct socket type for your broker.  If you want some form of load balancing so that you send to the next open service process, you'll need to use `ROUTER/REQ` and have each service indicate its availability and have the broker hold on to the message until the next service process says its available by sending results back.  If you want some other type of message handling, you'll have to indicate what that is so a suitable architecture can be proposed.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer, I clearly didn't understand the fact that REQ was expecting a reply before it could send another message. I've implemented the diagram and while there are no errors anymore, the messages don't reach their destination.  The SUB/DEALER proxy is subscribed to everything.  Can you confirm that the SUB/PUB and SUB/DEALER brokers are both running ZMQ.proxy?

Comment: Using a ZMQ proxy is probably the preferred way to do it.  Do you know where the message is getting stuck?  How far does it make it through?

Comment: I have no idea, what is the best way to trace it?

Comment: ZMQ.proxy() has a capture socket parameter, I'll try using this.

Comment: After looking at your test program, it looks like you *may* be falling victim to [a slow joiner](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Getting-the-Message-Out) - your "event publisher" thread connects the publisher and then *immediately* sends out a single message - the subscriber may not be finished setting up its subscription by the time you attempt to send your first message.  `PUB` sockets don't wait for the peer to finish connecting, they just drop the message if there are no subscribers.  I recommend you wait a sec before sending your message, or sending a bunch of messages in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly I got mixed up with a few elements:

- Sockets have the same API whether you're using it as a client-side socket (`Socket.connect`) or a server-side socket (`Socket.bind`)
- Sockets have the same API regardless of the type (e.g. `Socket.subscribe` should not be called on a `PUSH` socket)
- Some socket types require a send/receive response loop (e.g. `REQ/REP`)
- Some nuances in communication patterns (`PUSH/PULL` vs `ROUTER/DEALER`)
- The difficulty (impossiblity?) in debugging a ZeroMQ setup

So a big thanks to Jason for his incredibly detailed answer (and awesome diagram!) that pointed me to the right direction.

I ended up with the following design:

- broker thread 1 is running a fan-out `XSUB/XPUB` proxy on `bind(localhost:6000)` and `bind(localhost:6001)`
- broker thread 2 is running a queuing `SUB/PUSH` proxy on `connect(localhost:6001)` and `bind(localhost:6002)`; broker threads 3 and 4 use a similar design with different bind port numbers
- message producers connect to the broker using a `PUB` socket on `connect(localhost:6000)`
- message consumers connect to the broker queuing proxy using a `PULL` socket on `connect(localhost:6002)`

On top of this service-specific queuing mechanism, I was able to add a similar service-specific fan-out mechanism rather simply:

- broker thread runs a `SUB/PUB` proxy on `connect(localhost:6001)` and `bind(localhost:6003)`
- message producers still connect to the broker using a `PUB` socket on `connect(localhost:6000)`
- message consumers connect to the broker fan-out proxy using a `SUB` socket on `connect(localhost:6003)`

This has been an interesting ride.